# Automating a login with out providing the password via selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to create an automated test to one of my accounts. I have manage to do so but i have to provide the password via driver.sendKeys(). Any idea on how i could automate this part without providing my password? I have attached the code below

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LoginToTradeville {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://tradeville.eu/");

        driver.findElement(By.id("ac--two")).click();

        WebElement utilizator = driver.findElement(By.id("inputLogin"));
        utilizator.click();
        utilizator.sendKeys("Pradu");

        WebElement password =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_phContent_ucComposeLogin_ucLoginStartrade_pnlLoginStartrade\"]/input[2]"));
        password.click();
        password.sendKeys("");//should input password

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_phContent_ucComposeLogin_ucLoginStartrade_btnLogin\"]")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to bypass the password or you are looking for some encoded format of the password?

Comment: I was thinking of an encoded format for the password.

Comment: You can convert the password to base64 as pass but that can be decrypted easily.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance but if i use something like : byte[] encode = Base64.encodeBase64(str.getBytes());    
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='login_div']/form/div[2]/p[2]/input")).sendKeys(encode); i should define the str as  a string i want to import in the password tab thus displaying my initial password. I am missing something? Thank you.

Comment: is ok for you to have the password in plain text in your code? Or do you want a solution to avoid the sendKeys method and just put the pass there?

Comment: I would like to avoid having the password in plain sight. Currently i added the Base64 version of the password in the code but i would like to avoid that as well.Thank you.

Comment: I've added a response on how you can achieve your goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to avoid password plain in your tests, here are few workarounds used by myself:

1.Password as environment variable - in your test you will load the password from your env and use key events in order to paste the password instead of typing it. (paste fills the input with while the send keys will show you each character like typing)

```
//get password value from env
String pass = System.getenv("STRING_NAME");

//put the value in the clipboard - this avoid the copy action
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(pass);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);

//paste the value in your password field 
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement("PASS_INPUT_LOCATOR").click().build().perform();
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("v").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

2.Avoid login page - save Cookies at first run and then use them to access your page - [here is a nice tutorial on how to do it](https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html)

Answer (score 0):

After some research i opted to read the password from a .txt file on my computer which i will not upload to GIT:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoginToTradeville {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String data = null;
        File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\Radu\\Desktop\\java\\Tradeville.txt");

        if (myObj.exists()){
        try {
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
               while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                data = myReader.nextLine();
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Wrong file");
            return;
        }
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://tradeville.eu/");

        driver.findElement(By.id("ac--two")).click();

        WebElement utilizator = driver.findElement(By.id("inputLogin"));
        utilizator.click();
        utilizator.sendKeys("Pradu");

        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_phContent_ucComposeLogin_ucLoginStartrade_pnlLoginStartrade\"]/input[2]"));
        password.click();
        password.sendKeys(String.valueOf(data));


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_phContent_ucComposeLogin_ucLoginStartrade_btnLogin\"]")).click();
    }
}
```